# form data getting displayed in url despite using http method post

Tags: python, django

i am learning django app development and have written a  simple code to add two numbers. the form data is geting displayed in the url despite using http request method post. i dont want form data to be displayed in the url. Kindly help.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{'name':'pavan sunder'})

def add(request):
    val1 = int(request.POST["num1"])
    val2 = int(request.POST["num2"])
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request, 'result.html',{'result':res})
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>hello {{name}}</h1>

<form action="add" method='POST'>
{% csrf_token %}
    Enter 1st number:<input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    Enter 2nd number:<input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
Result:{{result}}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

[image: formdata in url]

Comment: probably its not a django issue and the very same form made post request in my local machine(I am using Firefox and MacOS)

Comment: What might be the issue??

Comment: TBH, I don't know. Maybe something else is messing with the form POST. Can you make sure that you don't have any other services like NGINX or anything else running in same port? Or simply restart the machine to see if it persists. I am just suggesting some random ideas

Comment: I am using chrome and windows

Comment: Ok I ll try restarting

Comment: Restarting worked ...thanks!!